# JMeter BeanShell PostProcessor to extract date until T (time zone)

Tags: parameters, jmeter, extract, beanshell

I am extracting Date from json in the following format: 1980-09-08T00:00:00Z. To reuse this I need only: 1980-09-08. So I trie dto use BeanShell postprocessor:

```
String varPurchaseDate = ${PurchaseDate};
log.info(varPurchaseDate);
String[] varDate = line.split("T");
log.info(varDate[0]);
```

I am getting error

```
2017/11/01 16:41:30 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: ``String varPurchaseDate = 1980-09-08T00:00:00Z; log.info(varPurchaseDate);'' Encountered "9" at line 1, column 32.
```

Please help. Also how will I be able to use the parameter as input, as varDate[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't reference [JMeter Variables or Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in script body, use "Parameters" section or code-based equivalents instead
2. [Since JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) [it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting

So

- Switch to [JSR223 Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)
- Tick `Cache compiled script if available` box
- Replace first line of your code with:

  ```
  String varPurchaseDate = vars['PurchaseDate']
  ```

---

One more recommendation is using JMeter built-in components where possible, particularly in your case you can use [__split() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__split) to get first part of your date like:

```
${__split(${PurchaseDate},date,T)}
```

It will generate the following variables:

```
date_1=1980-09-08
date_2=00:00:00Z 
date_n=2
```

So you will be able to refer the desired value as `${date_1}` where required

[image: JMeter Split Function Demo]

Comment: Thanks, I used the split function. Is the way to run the function is to add HTTP Sample and execute it in the Header? Looks ugly ...

Answer (score 0):

change your BeanShell postprocessor code to the below:

```
String varPurchaseDate = vars.get("PurchaseDate");
log.info(varPurchaseDate);
String[] varDate = varPurchaseDate.split("T");    
log.info(varDate[0]);    
vars.put("MyDate", varDate[0]);// store the value of varDate[0] in a jmeter variable
```

After that you can use **${MyDate}** as the value of your parameter.